# Ubuntu 16.04 installer can't find my SSD on my Dell XPS 15

Tags: 16.04, dell, xps

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Dell XPS 15, but the installer can't find my SSD.

I want to do a dual boot, keeping Ubuntu and Windows 10.

Comment: Can you see it in the live mode (Try Ubuntu without installing)?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to switch the SSD controller mode in BIOS settings (press F12 when booting) from "RAID" to "AHCI", as right now Linux doesn't have the firmware support for the former mode, so cannot recognise the SSD drive.

Comment: Switching from RAID to AHCI did work, the issue is  that every time I'll have to go through BIOS settings and switch RAID to AHCI.
My idea is that it shows me the two options straight away, without having to keep going through BIOS setup.

Comment: Did you save the BIOS settings after changes?

Comment: Yes I did. I realised that if RAID is not on, Windows doesn't work. So if I need switch between the two OS, I have to switch from RAID to AHCI or vice versa.

Comment: You will need to follow this guide https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ to switch Windows to AHCI.

Comment: I did it, but didn't work. Instead I had to reset Windows 10 because it wouldn't load anymore. I believe I'll have to format my SSD and install Windows 10 from the beginning..

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/932997/why-cannot-the-ubuntu-installer-recognize-my-ssd/933042#933042

Answer (score 1):

The guide by Sam Nicholls doesn't quite work with the latest Intel RST driver.  However, I used the following [solution](https://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/) switching Win10 into safe mode before the BIOS change and switching it back after AHCI is correctly installed as the new default, and it works on my Dell XPS 8930.