# Ubuntu 16.04 can't see my SSD partitions when installing alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I bought a new laptop that comes with Windows 10. 
When I get to **Installation Type** it gives me this:

[image: no types listed]

`fdisk` only sees my USB drive.

[image: fdisk output in terminal]

Windows disk management looks like this:

[image: Windows disk management with ESP, 2 primary partitions, recovery partition and 220GB unallocated, third partition left to right]

I have successfully installed Ubuntu on 3 other machines using this boot drive before.

I noticed it doesn't let me choose **Install alongside Windows**. Not sure if it's supposed to be after **Installation Type**.

Gparted looks like this:

[image: gparted apparently showing only USB]

Comment: Almost always Windows fast startup needs to be off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation And Windows updates turn it back on, so if issue in future, first then to check. Could be a few other issues. If very new computer, better to use 18.04. What model Lenovo? Have you updated UEFI from Lenovo, required for all systems, Both Windows & Linux have fixed kernels, but UEFI also must be updated for Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities.

Comment: Your configuration consists of a 30G SSD and a 500G HDD. The SSD was probably configured as a fast cache for the HDD. You currently have the SSD configured for Ubuntu. You'll have to break the two apart to install Ubuntu on the HDD. You'll have to check your BIOS to see if the disk subsystem is set for RAID, or something else.

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for fast response. It's Lenovo ideapad 720S-14IKB. In my power settings there's no option to check or uncheck fast startup. I don't know how to update UEFI from Lenovo. In system info it says BIOS Mode: UEFI, not sure if this is related.

Comment: @heynnema Hello. "You currently have the SSD configured for Ubuntu".  How did you get this conclusion and what does it mean? It seems like the ubuntu installation can't see the partition table. Again I know nothing about this so sorry if the question is dumb. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have an UEFI system as you have ESP as first partition. Many vendors call UEFI as BIOS, but UEFI is replacement for BIOS. Every vendor is different on updating, check you manual for your model. Most update from Windows. Many also update  from UEFI, if update file on FAT32 partition either in ESP or on flash drive (UEFI can only read FAT32 directly). Some also have you create a DOS bootable flash drive for update.if nVidia, you also need nomodeset boot parameter. See UEFI section: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I saw that drive E: was labelled as Ubuntu, so I thought that Ubuntu might be installed there... but more than likely, the Ubuntu installer wiped it and set it that way... incorrectly... with the wrong file system... or maybe you did that manually when you were trying to install it.

Comment: @heynnema E drive is actually my boot usb drive. I'm not sure if this changes anything that'll help me fix this.

Comment: Oh, in that case, check your BIOS disk setup and see if it's set to RAID, or something else.

Comment: why dont you try with 18.04 ?

Comment: @heynnema it is set to RAID.

Comment: @cmak.fr I don't have another boot. I'll remake the boot drive later.

Comment: @cmak.fr sadly 18.04 didnt work. same issue

Comment: Your problem is that in the BIOS the disk subsystem is set to RAID. Ubuntu doesn't know what to do with that. Let me put together a quickie answer to help you change the RAID setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your BIOS is set to RAID for the disk subsystem, and the Ubuntu installer doesn't know what to do with that. You need to change it to AHCI. Here are two ways to do it. Windows will not need to be reinstalled if you follow one of these methods.

Some folks have found the 2nd choice that I provide easier to do...

## Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files, as data loss is always a possibility!

You've got a single SSD set up in RAID mode, and the Ubuntu installer won't recognize your SSD until you switch your disk setting in the BIOS from RAID to AHCI.

Making that switch comes with some problems though, as Windows will no longer boot.

You don't need to reinstall Windows...

Below, you'll find two different ways to solve this problem. Some users found Choice #2 to be easier.

#Make sure to have a backup of your important Windows files!

<strike>**Choice #1:** Looking at this article https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/ will show you how to make the change without having to reinstall Windows.</strike>

- Boot to Windows with your current SATA controller configuration
- Open `Device Manager`
- Expand `Storage Controllers` and identify the `Intel SATA RAID Controller`
- View properties of the identified controller
- On the Driver tab, click the Update driver… button
- Browse my computer…, Let me pick…
- Uncheck `Show compatible hardware`
- Select `Microsoft` as manufacturer
- Select `Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller` as model #
- Accept that `Windows cannot confirm that this driver is compatible`
- Save changes, reboot to BIOS and change RAID SATA Controller to AHCI
- Save changes and reboot normally, hopefully to Windows

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration.

**Choice #2:** See http://triplescomputers.com/blog/uncategorized/solution-switch-windows-10-from-raidide-to-ahci-operation/

- Right-click the Windows Start Menu. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`.
- If you don’t see `Command Prompt` listed, it’s because you have already been updated to a later version of Windows.  If so, use this method instead to get to the Command Prompt:
   -  Click the Start Button and type `cmd`
   - Right-click the result and select `Run as administrator`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
   - If this command does not work for you, try `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`
- Restart the computer and enter BIOS Setup (the key to press varies between systems).
- Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies).
- Save changes and exit Setup and Windows will automatically boot to Safe Mode.
- Right-click the Windows Start Menu once more. Choose `Command Prompt (Admin)`
- Type this command and press ENTER: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
   - If you had to try the alternate command above, you will likely need to do so here also: `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`
- Reboot once more and Windows will automatically start with AHCI drivers enabled.

Comment: Thank you so much! Finally worked. Just curious, will the changes affect future usb storage drive usage in anyway?

Comment: @DopeyNULL shouldn't have any effect on USB storage.

Comment: Option #2 worked well for me: flex-5-1570.

Comment: @heynnema Once ubuntu installation completed, Can I change SATA Operation mode to RAID?

Comment: @PaulThomas No. Only the server installation will work with RAID.

Comment: @heynnema if I kept it as AHCI, would it create any issue with windows? Thanks

Comment: @PaulThomas No. Not as long as you followed my instructions. You should be able to still boot to Windows.