# Ubuntu installer won't recognize my SSD on Macbook Air

Tags: system-installation, ssd, macbook

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 on my laptop:

- **Model:** Macbook Air 11" (early 2015)
- **SSD:** APPLE SSD AP0128H (128 GB; PCI-Express)
- **Current SO:** MacOS 10.15.3 (Catalina)

At the step of selecting the disk to install, my SSD is not shown. Neither Gparted nor Fdisk can recognize it.
I thought the problem was the Ubuntu version, so I tried since the 14 to 19, but any version worked.

Then I tried with other distributions, like Fedora, ArchLinux or Debian, but these didn't recognize it, as well. Only Deepin can recognize my SSD, but I don't want to install deepin. I was looking into the Deepin iso a driver for my SSD to copy it into the Ubuntu iso, but I don't know where the drivers are placed.

This isn't the first time I tried to install Ubuntu on my Macbook. A year ago I installed it with no problem, but this year is not working.

PS: My native language is not English, so I beg you to understand that my grammar couldn't be perfect. In a last post, a user criticized my grammar. Also, it's a little bit hard to describe my problem in other language.

Thank you.

**Update:**

 I tried to access to my bios settings to change the RAID to AHCI, but I don't know how to do that on Mac.

I have the same problem like [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041305/ubuntu-16-04-cant-see-my-ssd-partitions-when-installing-alongside-windows-10).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles across the same issue as described by Saúl, I solved it by adding `intel_iommu=off` in the live cd kernel options (at boot time).