# Can't install Ubuntu on my second hdd

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop. I have one sdd where I have windows 10, office and main docs, and a hdd where I have heavy software and files, here I want to install Ubuntu. I made a 120 gb partition for Ubuntu and it doesn't detect it. I tried partition with fat 32, ntfs and ext4 formats. I found this topic: [Ubuntu 16.04 can't see my SSD partitions when installing alongside Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041305/ubuntu-16-04-cant-see-my-ssd-partitions-when-installing-alongside-windows-10)

[image]

I don't if it will apply to my case. I will install a separately EFI to avoid windows corruption. What should i do?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! For sure you can't use nor NTFS or FAT to install Ubuntu (or any linux). How did you partition the disk? Did you use GParted? Can you show a screenshot of it? selecting your hdd of course.

Comment: Hi, i´m using miniTool for partitions. I just posted a screenshot where you can see disk 2 with my files and program partition and the ext4 partition.

Comment: GParted can´t see the partion.

Comment: Don't use windows tool to create linux partitions (EXT4, which is what you need). Post a screenshot of GParted.

Comment: I updated the post with a photo.

Comment: You have a 223gb disk where I assume you have windows installed. In linux this disk is called `/dev/sda`. Then you have a 465gb where you want to install Ubuntu, that in linux terms should be `/dev/sdb`In your screenshot of GParted the disk shown is `/dev/sda`, you have to select the disk `/dev/sdb`. Look at the top right corner it says `/dev/sda 223.57 GB`. Click there and you will see the other disk, which is where you want Ubuntu installed.

Comment: I just noticed that. I made fresh partition using GP. I will star the install process again.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  My Ubuntu was installed successfully.

Comment: Glad to hear! Enjoy :)