# Dual Boot Windows 10 with Ubuntu 16

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hibernate

I was trying to dual boot my Windows 10 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I have followed all the steps mentioned but when I boot into the Linux USB and try to Install Ubuntu , I get a blank white screen in the step Installation Type. I do not get any options which normally would appear in the Installation type step such as

1. Install Alongside Windows
2. Erase Disc
3. Something Else

PS : Windows 10 fast startup/hibernate already disabled
     UEFI Boot mode as default with Secure Boot Disabled
     Windows Disc Partitions are also not read by Ubuntu.

Please Help !!

Comment: Are installing both windows and ubuntu on the same disk? Why do you prefer ubuntu 16.04 over ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip. Many need boot parameters. Also have you updated UEFI from vendor and if SSD updated firmware?

Comment: @Marmayogi - I have partitioned my C Drive to generate an unallocated Drive. I am running ROS Kinetic for my projects and it is supported only by Ubuntu 16

Comment: @oldfred I have just checked my hard drive and it is a 1TB SSD . Maybe that is why the drives are not read by Ubuntu. If I am not mistaken I will have to install the SSD Drivers or Linux right?

PS : DELL PRECISION 5520
        Intel Xeon 
        NVidia 4GB Graphics
        1TB SSD

Comment: i.e  you have shrunk your 1 TB SSD and divided into two partitions. In the first one windows-10 is already present and attempting to install ubuntu 16.04 on the newly created partition. Can you tell me what is the size of 2nd partition, newly created one? Are you using bootable USB stick? How did you prepare the USB stick? Did you select the following: 1. “Partition scheme” to “GPT” 2. “UEFI (non CSM).  Did you set the USB stick priority in BIOS setup screen? `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are for windows and Ubuntu respectively. Did you see these devices while installing ubuntu using USB stick?

Comment: Dells all need UEFI updates, SSD firmware updates, drives set to AHCI (but install Windows ACHI driver first) and with nVidia you will need nomodeset boot partameter. Windows pre-installed will be UEFI, so you must boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode to install in UEFI mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap  & 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: @Marmayogi - I have created a Live Bootable Ubuntu USB Stick. The Size of my second partition is 300GB. While writing the ISO to the USB i chose partition scheme as UEFI or BIOS.While booting up I ran the ubuntu in USB stick by pressing F12. I have not changed the bootup priority. Windows still has higher Boot Priority. In Ubuntu when i search for Disks I find only my USB Stick. The SSD Partitions are not visible at all.

Comment: @oldfred Will I need to change over my BIOS Settings ? I have read that Ubuntu does not read a SSD setup in Raid. 

https://askubuntu.com/questions/932997/why-cannot-the-ubuntu-installer-recognize-my-ssd

Comment: Standard desktop does not have RAID drivers, but Ubuntu works fine with RAID. But Dell and some others use RAID even if one drive. Only if you have RAID 0 should you not change setting to AHCI. Intel SRT is usually what is setting & Intel says AHCI works just as well.

Comment: Kasheesh, had you used `Rufus` tool to prepare your bootable USB stick, you could have selected `"Partition Scheme" as GPT` and `“Target system” as “UEFI (non CSM)`. Though your windows-10 is pre-installed with UEFI, however there is nothing wrong in verifying this veracity, by refering [how to verify Partition style/sheme](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-convert-mbr-disk-gpt-move-bios-uefi-windows-10) and make sure that Windows-10 shows up `GUID Partition Table (GPT)` as `parition style`. You may need to re-prepare your USB bootable stick for ubuntu using `Rufus` with right parameters.