# INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE in Windows 10 after changing SATA Configuration from RAID ON to AHCI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, raid, ahci

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Dual Boot Windows 10 Alienware Laptop. At first, the live Ubuntu installer couldn't detect the SSD inside so I changed the SATA configuration from RAID ON to AHCI. I could install Ubuntu without any problem after that.

However, because of changing to AHCI, now Windows 10 is not booting up and showing INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE. Luckily, I was able to boot Windows 10 even after installing Ubuntu by changing the SATA configuration back to RAID ON. Then I followed the steps written [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/933042/569883) and changed "Storage Controllers" from Intel to Microsoft. Finally, I changed back to AHCI in boot options.

Later on, I also installed the [Boot Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on Ubuntu thinking that it will solve the issue. However, I still can not log in to Windows 10.

Any workaround, please?

Comment: `boot-repair` only works if you run it from a live session

Comment: @Nmath: Thank you very much. There is an entry of Windows OS in the GRUB menu. However, it seems that Windows is not able to find out the boot record. It is throwing the INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error. Any workaround, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work after booting Windows 10 in safe mode for once. After that, it worked well.

Please read the complete instructions from [here](https://superuser.com/a/1359471).

Comment: Thank you. I switched from Intel RST to AHCI and Windows booted. I found online articles saying that it should not boot, but also an article which said that newer versions of Windows would boot also after the switch without previous changes.

Comment: @raffaem : I confirmed that running Windows 10 in safe boot only once is enough. It works.